# Can rows exist after columns in html?

Tags: html, row, frameset, col

i'm trying ot make a page where there are 2 columns to the left using  then have the space to the right be occupied by 2 rows in the top and the bottom of the page, but whenever i load the page the 2 columns will be the only thing occupying all of it.

this is what i have so far:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Frames</title>
 </head>
 <frameset cols="20%,20%">
   <frame name="leftleft" src="menu1.html">
   <frame name="leftright" src="menu2.html">
 </frameset>  
   <frameset rows="50%,50%">
        <frame name="top" src="cabecera.html">
        <frame name="bottom" src="sample.html">
   </frameset>
</html>
```

i've tried moving the s around, changing the values after cols and rows and nothing seems to work, only the columns will show up.
this is my first question here, any help is greatly appretiated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

Comment: As pointed out, you need to know that framesets have been obsolete, not just deprecated, for 20 years or more.

Comment: @Rob i needed to do this for an assignment, thank you anyways for taking the time to let me know.